# The foundations of Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

I started programming proofs in Isabelle one year and a half ago. Back then I mostly wrote Isabelle/Isar proofs. More recently, I have been doing a little of programming at the Isabelle/ML level. I found very inspiring [this PhD thesis](https://mediatum.ub.tum.de/doc/601724/601724.pdf) that describes the construction of Isar. I was wondering if there is a similar source to learn about Isabelle's foundations. I found [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/cs/9301105) from 1989 and [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/cs/9301106) from 1990 by Larry Paulson. Does this describe the current foundations of the system?

**Update:**

I found what so far is the clearest explanation of Isabelle/Pure in [Joshua Chen's](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1911.00399.pdf) thesis. There is the separate concern on how the kernel [hides theorem creation](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/121015/how-the-kernel-works-in-a-lcf-theorem-prover). But this seems to be a language feature based on abstract data types.

**Update 2**

There has been some discussion on the Isabelle's mailing list under the subject *Explanation of derivation in Isabelle's formal system*. A further reference that was pointed out there was the [Isabelle/Isar implementation reference](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/website-Isabelle2019/dist/Isabelle2019/doc/implementation.pdf). This stands for a revised version of the above PhD thesis.

Comment: A good account of the current status is here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1907.02836.pdf

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14703998/core-of-verifier-in-isabelle-hol